# Accessing Twitter Data - Failed authentication with valid credentials

Tags: spring-boot, twitter-oauth

I've downloaded the code from Spring's Get Started Guide - Accessing Twitter Data the https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/ .

I set up my credentials in application.properties and made no other changes.  I run the app, and when it attempts to connect to Twitter, it fails with an exception on ConnectController line 240:

> ResourceAccessException: 
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   POST request for "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token":cannot
>   retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode; nested
>   exception is java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server
>   authentication, in streaming mode

I have checked that the credentials are being read by the app.  They are valid - I use them to connect with another application I've written with twitter4j, although in that case I use a Token and Token Secret in addition to the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Yep, see Bienestas' answer.  Just add a callback url in your appliction details on Twitter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue as you : it happened because I did not set my callback URL in the twitter setting.

Just check in your twitter app settings that the callback field is set (I used the same URL as the website field).

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back.  This was exactly the problem.  Thanks.